# Sufficient condition for a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $x_{1}<x_{2}$ in $[a,b] \Rightarrow f(x_2)-f(x_1) \geq k(x_2-x_1)$ for some fixed positive constant k.
Is the function $f$ Lipschitz on $[a,b]$?
Note: The above condition implies $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$

Comment: Not necessarily, consider $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if the inequality is right. I mean everything works fine if $f(x_{2})-f(x_{1})\leq k(x_{2}-x_{1})$ for some positive costant $k$.

In fact the definition of Lipschitz continuity is that for any $x,y\in [a,b]$ exists a positive constant $L$ such that
\begin{equation}
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x_{2}-x_{1}|.
\end{equation}

Recall that $Lip((a,b)) \subset C^{0}([a,b])$, hence if the function is Lipschitz is also continous. In particular if $f$ is stricly increasing there's no need of the absolute value and you get the desired conclusion.

Comment: The inequality is right. I was wondering if the class of functions as described by my hypothesis was contained in the class of Lipschitz functions.

Comment: See my comment, then you know it is not